# how can i download php using wget

Tags: ubuntu, php

I went to the php website and tried to download the latest php using wget (from ssh). but there doesn't seem to be any direct link only mirrors.

when i download using the mirror link it just creates a file named mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click the main link and then you get directed to a page that has all the downloads from the different mirrors.. From there you can use wget

```
# wget http://us.php.net/get/php-5.3.5.tar.bz2/from/us3.php.net/mirror

--2011-01-19 05:08:48--  http://us.php.net/get/php-5.3.5.tar.bz2/from/us3.php.net/mirror
Resolving us.php.net... 208.69.120.58
Connecting to us.php.net|208.69.120.58|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://us3.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.5.tar.bz2 [following]
--2011-01-19 05:08:49--  http://us3.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.5.tar.bz2
Resolving us3.php.net... 192.41.42.26
Connecting to us3.php.net|192.41.42.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 10806092 (10M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: “php-5.3.5.tar.bz2”
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the option `-O filename` like this `wget -O outputfile http://example.com/your/path` and retrieve the *outputfile* in your current directory.